# JPAContainer and JPA version

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, vaadin

It is mandatory to use in my [vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) web project JBOSS 5.1.
Since JBOSS 5.1 does not support JPA 2.1 by default, I need to use JPA 1.0

So, what about [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-jpacontainer:vaadin)?

It says in addon directory:

> In case you are still using JPA 1.0 implementation you should use 
>   older version of  JPAContainer which can be downloaded by selecting
>   1.2.x version from Version drop-down list. But when I select version 1.2.1, it shows compatibility only with Vaadin 6.6.x

1. Can I use JPAContainer 1.2.1 in a Vaadin 7.3.3 project? If yes, what would be the drawbacks
2. OR, Can I use JPAContainer 3.1.1 with JPA 1.0 ? If yes, what would be the drawbacks

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPAContainer 1.2.1 is not compatible with Vaadin 7+, so your only solution, since I firmly suggest to do not roll back on Vaadin6, is to stick with JPAContainer 3+

You can use JPA 1.0 if you wish, simply when you add JPA facet in your project select the "1.0" version and use the right implementation. Don't forget the right header in the persistence.xml file.

About the drawbacks, on wikipedia you can read the major changes
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API
Worst thing I see is the loss of "criteria query API" and "support for validation" and **imho those are huge**.
BUT even without "criteria query API" you can use Filter in JPAContainer (which can be used as a simple criteria query..) and you can perform validation though Vaadin.
All in all I'd say is manageable, if you cannot move away from your bounds.